# Add new column to existing table CloudSQL Postgres 9.6

Tags: google-cloud-sql

When adding a column to an existing table (without specifying a default value), does CloudSQL rewrite the entire table + indexes or does it simply update the metadata, the way Postgres 9.6 does? Asking because I tried adding a column to a large table today (200 million rows) and it took an extremely long time to finish, which makes me think that CloudSQL is rewriting the table/indexes.

Comment: I think this just should be the same as CloudSQL is just serverless Postgres implementation. How do you run this command?

Comment: Thanks. We're using the Elixir language to run the migrations. It might be something to do with that, although when i looked at the cloudsql active queries it was running a simple `alter table add column` command